# How to set up CLion on Mac

Tags: macos, configuration, clion

I installed CLion and I am trying to run some code, but when it asks for a configuration there is none available, even though the environment seems setup correctly.
[Toolchains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zMkY.png)
[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixu8u.png)

I could not find a setup guide for MacOS online. What am I missing?
Would anyone be able to put together a quick how-to covering the basics?
It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it a CMake project? Configurations are created automatically for each CMake target. Build All target is a default CMake target for building all targets in the project and it doesn't have an executable by default. You can specify one or Run specific per target configuration

Comment: I am trying to run a simple C program.

Comment: Do you have a CMake project? CLion can't work without a CMake project

Comment: There are the files I have: [Image](https://imgur.com/a/AjouB)
I guess I am asking for a quick "Hello World" how to guide from scratch.

Comment: @David have you solved your problem? If so how?

Comment: I have not. I know a make file is required but not sure what it should contain.